# How to adjust borders on CloudHQ gmail template?

Tags: html, gmail

So I'm using the cloud HQ gmail template provider. It has a drag and drop feature but doesn't get to stick the borders together even though i have already adjusted the `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` to 0.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to install the Gmail Email Templates extension by cloudHQ https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-email-templates/llccdnmbipddnkhmldacpcjjcnljpoij/

   2. Compose an email in Gmail, and click the new icon on the bottom that says “Insert Template” button on your Gmail to select an email template: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7ZPX.png
   3. It looks like you clicked on the template "Free trial"
   4. If you want to change something in the HTML editor, click on the icon on the bottom of your Gmail email's compose window:
      https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ73u.jpg
   5. I think you're confusing cell spacing versus padding spacing.

The cell spacing attribute specifies the space, in pixels, between cells and within a cell.

To set cell padding in HTML, use the style attribute. The style attribute specifies an inline style for an element. The attribute is used with the HTML table tag, with the CSS property padding.

Here's an image that might help you understand: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0boF.jpg

6. And here's an example of what it looks like with 0px padding vs 18px padding: https://www.cloudhq.net/c/76c431458a
7. For more details about how to adjust borders on Gmail Email Templates, please follow the link below:
   https://support.cloudhq.net/how-to-adjust-borders-on-gmail-email-templates/

Answer (score 0):

Can you add  **line-height:0;** Property.